# how to change index directory of my laravel website

Tags: laravel, server, localhost, hosting, host

I want to create a website using Laravel Framework in my localhost **laragon server**

I uploaded the website files in a Web Hosting. and when I enter the url `http://www.mywebsite.com`. then I just get the files like

[image]

But when I enter the url `http://www.mywebsite.com/public` then it is working perfectly.

Can anyone suggest me that what's I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your domain to public folder of laravel not root since laravel has index.php inside `project folder/public/index.php` so you need to point `project folder/public/`

Comment: @mrprogra002.yes exactly .point your domain to that folder.it works fine .

Comment: @mrprogra002.are you using shared hosting or vps ?

Comment: then you need to contact hosting provider to point your primary domain to public folder

Comment: i have 2 websites in my HOST, the primary domaine works fine, but this is the second domain..

Comment: then you goto addon domain in your hosting and edit root path for your domain

Comment: the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you uploaded your application to `/var/www/html` directory. and your public folder path looks like this `/var/www/html/public`.

Then your `site-available` file code should be like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
```

You just need to change `root` path. Then your site will work properly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- i moved all files from public folder (project_folder/public/ )

  into project folder
- in index.php i changed this lines:

  - require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
  - $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    INTO:
  - require **DIR**.'/./vendor/autoload.php';
  - $app = require_once **DIR**.'/./bootstrap/app.php';

    **and works fine** ...
    Thank you to everyone :)